# How do I merge the indexes in an array to create 1 main array/String in Java?

Tags: java

The input is supposed to be

```
ABDECDEABCAADD
ABCDE
```

The first line is a random piece of text. The second line is a circular shift.

The output is supposed to be:

```
yes
```

This program is supposed to take a piece of text and determine if it contains a circular shift based on the second line of input.
A circular shift is when you take the first letter of the string and move it to the back of the string. Thus creating a new string.

If the text entered contains a circular shift from the second line then the output would be yes otherwise it would be no.

Since ABDECDEABCAADD contains DEABC which is a shift of ABCDE the output would be yes.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String text;
    
    
    System.out.println("Enter text:");
    text=scan.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Enter shift:");
    String shift=scan.nextLine();
    
    
    String[] split1=shift.split("");
    String[] array2=new String[split1.length];
    String[] array3=new String[split1.length];
    
    for(int z=0;z<split1.length;z++) {
    
        array2[split1.length-1]=split1[0];
    
        for(int x=0;x<split1.length-1;x++) {
            array2[x]=split1[x+1];
            array3[0]=array2[x]+array2[x+1];
        }
        
    //if(text!=)
    }
    
    for(int y=0;y<array2.length;y++) {
        System.out.print(array2[y]);
    }
```

How I wanted to tackle this question was to first get the input then separate the second line into characters so I can create a circular shift. Once I'm done with that I would take the new order of characters and merge them to create a string.

I need help when it comes to the merging but also with how I can create multiple shifts.
If you see this pleas help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create shifts. For best performance, do it like this:

```java
String text = "ABDECDEABCAADD";
String shift = "ABCDE";
```

1. Scan `text` for the first character in `shift`, i.e. scan for `'A'`.
2. When found, match as many of the following characters as possible.
3. If not all characters in `shift` were matched, get the count of missing characters.
4. Grab that many characters from before the found `'A'`, if available.
5. If found and they match the remaining characters in `shift`, your search is done.
6. Repeat from step 1, searching for the next `'A'`.

*Example*

```java
static int matchShift(String text, String shift) {
    if (shift.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Shift value is empty");
    char first = shift.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (text.charAt(i) == first) {
            int j = 1;
            while (j < shift.length() && i + j < text.length()
                   && text.charAt(i + j) == shift.charAt(j))
                j++;
            if (j == shift.length())
                return i; // Match found at index 'i', with unshifted value
            int start = i + j - shift.length();
            if (start >= 0 && text.substring(start, i).equals(shift.substring(j, shift.length())))
                return start; // Match found at index 'start', with shifted value
        }
    }
    return -1; // No match found
}
```

*Test*

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("ABDECDEABCAADD", "ABCDE");
}

static void test(String text, String shift) {
    int i = matchShift(text, shift);
    if (i == -1)
        System.out.printf("'%s', '%s': No Match%n", text, shift);
    else
        System.out.printf("'%s', '%s': Match at index %d ('%s')%n",
                          text, shift, i, text.substring(i, i + shift.length()));
}
```

*Output*

```
'ABDECDEABCAADD', 'ABCDE': Match at index 5 ('DEABC')
```

It could also have responded with `Match at index 4 ('CDEAB')`. If that is important, change the logic to search for the *last* character instead of the *first*, match backwards, then compare substrings *after*.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you!